# AR(p) Covariance Matrix

Tags: matrices, covariance, time-series

So I have seen specific derivations of covariance matrices for AR(2) and AR(1) processes. However, I have not seen one for a general AR(p) process.

Suppose I know the coefficients of a given AR(p) polynomial. How can I construct the covariance matrix for this process? Is there a general form one can plug and play from?

Lets assume that the series represented by these coefficients is zero mean.

Comment: See [this](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/25063/1/S00086ED1V01Y200712SPR003.pdf) p.21

Comment: Perhaps better: see [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwji5dPl-trgAhWpyoMKHUxsDuYQFjAAegQIChAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww-stat.wharton.upenn.edu%2F~steele%2FCourses%2F956%2FResource%2FYWSourceFiles%2FYW-Eshel.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Fbb2i-B7Gs1togdNnviEL). Note this downloads a PDF.